# Webkit webkit_dom_document_evaluate function documentation

Tags: c, xpath, webkit, gtk

I am looking for guidance executing xpath in webkit/gtk/c code. It seems like there is a function webkit_dom_document_evaluate that should do what I want to do based on bug report at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42115

However I could not find any documentation of this method nor could I locate any example of using this call. I am especially curious about "type" parameter. Above bug passes value 7, but I have no idea what that value stands for.

Is this the right way to execute xpath in webkit? To avoid confusion, I need to make the call from c side of the world using WebKitDomDocument object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value type is a `XPathResult` as defined in *XPath DOM Level 3* Spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathResult

Value *7* means *Ordered Node Snapshot Type*.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathResult-ORDERED-NODE-SNAPSHOT-TYPE

Yes, you can use this `evaluate` function in GTK using the GObject bindings. I actually added a test that shows how to do that. Check it here:

https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=203923&action=review